# How can I show that $E((Y - E(Y|X))^2) = 0$?

Tags: probability

I can expand this as:
$$E(Y^2) - 2E(YE(Y|X)) + E(E(Y|X)^2).$$

I believe $$E(YE(Y|X)) = E(E(Y|X)^2).$$

In the discrete case, I can write $$E(E(Y|X)^2) = \sum_x \left(\sum_y y \frac{P(Y=y, X=x)}{P(X=x)} \right)^2 P(X=x).$$
It doesn't seem like this is equal to $E(Y^2)$. What am I missing here?

Comment: The thing you want to prove is not generally true. In particular, $\mathbb E[Z^2]$ will only be $0$ if $Z=0$ with probability $1$, and we don't have $Y - \mathbb E[Y\mid X] = 0$ with probability $1$ unless $Y$ is a function of $X$.

Comment: Well if $Y$ and $X$ are independent then $E(Y\mid X) = E(Y)$, so you'd be claiming that $\mathop{\text{Var}}(Y) = 0$. That's not true in general, so you would definitely need some (strong) hypothesis to get this to work. What could that hypothesis be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Your claim is false. For example, consider the case that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. In this case, $E(Y\mid X) = E(Y)$. Then, your expression reduces to $E((Y-E(Y))^2)=0$. However, $E((Y-E(Y))^2)$ is the variance of $Y$ and in general, it is non-zero unless $Y$ is constant (a.e.).